# User level security in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am using Tableau 10.1.1.

There is one report that I need to block most of the user and allow access to only very select subset of users. How can this be done in Tableau?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a group for the select subset of users (see [Add Users to a Group](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/users_add_group.htm)) and then grant access to only that group (see [Permissions Reference](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/license_permissions.htm)).